# The underlying provider failed on open entity framework

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am unsing entity framework in my web application. Earlier everything was working fine. But then I deleted database from Sql Server. After that whenever I run the application, I get the following exception :

```
The underlying provider failed on open entity framework
```

Isn't it true that if we delete the database from Sql Server and again run the application, database is again created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you show some details about connection string. I basically want to check the authentication you are using.
Demo for setting a typical authentication : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649314.aspx

Another possibility can be with connection pooling. Try explicitly closing the connection(if there are any open connections)

```
db.Database.Connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Entity framework will recreate your database on application start assuming the following:

- You have permission to create databases in SQL
- A connection string is specified correctly (if it was working before this should be fine)
- You are using CodeFirst or ModelFirst strategies for databases (ie if you generated an EDMX off an existing database it wont recreate it for you)

Comment: The error that you have gotten normally relates to either a permission or connection based issue. I would recommend troubleshooting around weather the user running your app (or in the conn string) can both access and create the database. Try doing it manually using those credentials.

Comment: Yeah check you can login (from the machine running the app, SSMS works for me), create a db and run a create table script, its probably also worth confirming that you have deleted/moved the .mdf and .ldf files on the SQL box so you dont get a name conflict.

Comment: Also just make sure you havent applied another behavior for EF, the following is default: `System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<SampleContext>());` see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6131926/1070291

Comment: Yes, I am able to add database and create table from SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and it was due to the connection problem.
Usually you need to open your *.EDPS file under your entity (EDML) and check your connection string and make sure it has got a correct setting especially your Default Oracle home.