# Proper Provider Format for Connection String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string

Probably a simple question but proving difficult for me to locate an answer for my situation.

*MVC 4, C# Application using Visual Studio express 2012*

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4) and am trying to switch connection strings from local database (works) to MS SQL database hosted on-line (1and1 server).

The connection info provided by the online provider is:

```
Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=db501044113.db.1and1.com,1433;Initial Catalog=db501044113;User Id=dbo501044113;Password=*****;
```

My connection string is this:

```
<add name="RCDBContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=db501044113.db.1and1.com,1433;Initial Catalog=db501044113;User Id=dbo501044113;Password=*****" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
/>
```

When I load my page I'm met with a permission denied error: `CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.`

**Why is it trying to create an existing database?**

Most of the Google answers I'm finding are talking about server side permissions.  Since my database is hosted by third party I don't have access to these permissions.  It doesn't seem like I should need it either as this is a common service provided.

**Do I really need to change server side permissions or is my application at fault?**

Maybe something to do with Entity Framework and code first?

I tried using the `Provider=sqloledb` in the connection string but got a different error.  Should I be using something other than `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`  with this type of provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution ended up being a little different type of initializer.  Instead setting one of the three options:

- CreateDatabaseIfNotExists
- DropCreateDatabaseAlways
- DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

I just set it to `null` like this:

```
Database.SetInitializer<RCDBContext>(null);
```

Also, for those who are wonder where to put this code, add it to your `Global.asax` file inside the `Application_Start()` method.

For example, this is what mine looks like:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

        Database.SetInitializer<RCDBContext>(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not your Connectionstring but rather your code that tries to regenerate the database.

[Entity Framework 4 Code First - Prevent DB Drop/Create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131840/entity-framework-4-code-first-prevent-db-drop-create)

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<SampleContext>());
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I read a little about this and looks like the code should be in `Application_Start()`.  This will still try to create a new one if it's not found which might be my problem since I still get the same error.  Any other suggestions?